# How to determine which options selected in multiple <select>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have this `<select>`:

```
 <select id="week" multiple="multiple" >
    <option value="1">Monday</option>
    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
    <option value="5">Friday</option>
    <option value="6">Saturday</option>
    <option value="7">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

How can I know that whether each `<option>` is selected or not in jQuery or JS?

Comment: @Moshtaf I think this is not duplicated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .is :

```
 $('#week option').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':selected')){
      //code
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector to grab the selected option elements,

```
$('#week option:selected').each(function(){
   //Your code to manipulate things over selected option elements
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length` property of selected and total options, see below jquery :

```
var totalOptions = $('#week option').length; // all options available
var selectedOptions = $('#week option:selected').length;// selected options

if(totalOptions == selectedOptions)
 alert('All options selected');
else
 alert('Not all options selected');
```